# Ignore a word in AJAX template using API

Tags: ajax, api, cpu-word

I'm using an api to create a quiz. The code that fetches the gif from the app Loopcam and then puts the loop title in the div #answer looks like this:

```
APP = {
  refresh: function(limit, interval) {
    APP.index(limit);
    setInterval(function () {APP.index(limit)}, interval)
  },
  index: function(limit) {
    var url = 'https://api.loopc.am/v1/loops/search?q=moviecharades'

    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(data) {
        var data = data
          , html
          , templatedata
          , template = '{{#loops}}<div id="answer">{{title}}</div><div class="loop-tumbnail"><img src="{{file_url}}" {{loop_url}}/></div>{{/loops}}'
          , offset = Math.round(Math.random() * (data.length - 1))
          
       TITLE = data[0].title
          console.log(offset)

        if (data.length > 0) {
          data = data.slice(offset, offset + limit);

          templatedata = {loops: data}
          html = Mustache.to_html(template, templatedata)

          $('#loops').html(html)
        }
      }
    })
```

What I need is the word "#moviecharades" to be deleted from the div #answer, which is always in the title that is fetched from the API. In short: if the title that is fetched is "#moviecharades big fish", I want it to only say "big fish" in the #answer-div.

I've tried to put it as a rule for the #answer-div, such as:

```
$("#answer").text($("#answer").text().replace("#moviecharades", ""));
```

But it doesn't work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var answerText = $("#answer").text();
$("#answer").text( answerText.replace("#moviecharades", ""));
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I tried putting it in the HTML, that didn't work. Should I put it in the AJAX?

Comment: I got confused for a moment.  Just pasted your original code for `replace` into JSFiddle and it sucessfully changes the string in the way that you want.  I thought that was the problem -- guess not.  YES, try the `replace` (your or mine, doesn't matter) as the last line of `if` statement in your `$.ajax` `success` method.